# Why I can't install blender 2.78 x64?

Tags: installation

Error installing blender 2.78 x64 on windows 10 x64, it says "The cabinet file `media1.cab` required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used."

[image]

Comment: There is a bug in the 2.78 release installer currently, the devs mention it will be fixed for 2.78a. See http://www.blendernation.com/2016/10/09/blender-developers-meeting-notes-october-9-2016/

Comment: @aliasguru they should not post the download link there, it's a waste of time

Comment: @aliasguru what version should I download?

Comment: Download the zip archive instead, simply unzip it, run blender.exe from that. In a few days they plan to do the a release. This was a bug very hard to spot, so it is understandable they missed it.

Comment: @aliasguru even the zip is corrupted